# Retrieving historical queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I use the following query to retrieve the current queries running on server:

```
select *
from (
    select
    t1.session_id,
    t1.request_id,
    t3.hostname,
    t3.loginame,
    t3.login_time,
    cast(t3.waittime as bigint) / 60000  as wait_time,
    cast(t2.cpu_time as bigint) / 60000  as cpu_time,
    cast(t2.total_elapsed_time as bigint) / 60000 as total_elapsed_time,
    --t3.program_name,
    db_name (t3.dbid) as dbname,
    t1.task_alloc  * (8.0/1024.0) as Alocado_MB, --qtd de paginas
    t1.task_dealloc  * (8.0/1024.0)as Desalocado_MB, --qtd de paginas

        (SELECT SUBSTRING(text, t2.statement_start_offset/2 + 1,
              (CASE WHEN statement_end_offset = -1
                  THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),text)) * 2
                       ELSE statement_end_offset
                  END - t2.statement_start_offset)/2)
         FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(t2.sql_handle)) AS query_text,
    (SELECT query_plan from sys.dm_exec_query_plan(t2.plan_handle)) as query_plan
    from      (Select session_id, request_id,
    sum(internal_objects_alloc_page_count +   user_objects_alloc_page_count) as task_alloc,
    sum (internal_objects_dealloc_page_count + user_objects_dealloc_page_count) as task_dealloc
           from sys.dm_db_task_space_usage
           group by session_id, request_id) as t1,
           sys.dm_exec_requests as t2,
           sys.sysprocesses as t3
    where
        t3.loginame <> '' and
        t1.session_id = t2.session_id and
        (t1.request_id = t2.request_id) and
        t1.session_id = t3.spid and
        t1.session_id > 50
) A
order by loginame, total_elapsed_time DESC
```

**Is there a way to retrieve the historical ones?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
SELECT  a.plan_handle ,
        a.sql_handle ,
        e.text    
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats a
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.plan_handle) AS e
WHERE text like '%somevalue%'  --If you want to filter some values
```

Comment: This is great. Is there a way to know the historical queries from a specific login?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no. Once a query has been submitted, compiled, and processed, that's it -- SQL itself does not keep a record of what queries were submitted or when they were run.

Compiled plans *are* stored, against the chance that the same query may be submitted so as to avoid the cost of complication. These are stored in the procedure cache, and are "aged out" over time based on use and system load. You can use them to see what's in there now, but you could never assume that this provided a comprehensive look at what your system has been running at any point in time. (The key system objects here are `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` and `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`.)

SQL Profiler (or rather, SQL Traces) could be configured to track everything an instance ever runs, but this would incur a possibly unacceptable performance hit.

**Disclaimer**: this is applicable through SQL 2008. SQL 2012+ might have this kind of functionality, but I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to recover the queries that are in still in cache for a specific login?

Comment: As you explained, I guess no, right? (since the only important thing here is the plan itself and not the historical metadata about that plan)

Comment: I'm pretty sure not. I know you can determine what login a currently executing plan is running for, and there's something with multiple compilations of a single query based on login parameters, but I've never really dived into that and it is likely that MS has modified it in 2012+.